# R datesequence getting indices of certain dates

Tags: r, date

I have a sequence of dates in daily frequence. Now I need the indices of the first day of every month and the last day of every month. I have no idea how to achieve this.

```
# Just a simple datesequence
dateSeq <- seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-01"), to=as.Date("2017-01-01"), by="day")
```

I need a vector with all indices of the first day of month (1, 32,...) and the last day of the month (31, 68,...)

EDIT: I also need it with the first and last day of a week, year, semester, two months and half year so there should be a consistent way of doing it

If the datesequence ends on the 12th March 2017 for example I do not need this day to be in the indices, because it is not the last day of the month but the last day of the month in the sequence.

Comment: can you paste a part of your data (dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are indices of the first and last day of months and Weekdays as well

library(lubridate)

```
b=unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month"))
> match(b,dateSeq)
 [1]    1   32   60   91  121  152  182  213  244  274  305  335  366  397  425  456  486  517  547  578  609  639  670  700  731  762  790  821  851  882  912  943
[33]  974 1004 1035 1065 1096 1127 1156 1187 1217 1248 1278 1309 1340 1370 1401 1431 1462

> c=unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month"))-1
> match(c,dateSeq)
 [1]   NA   31   59   90  120  151  181  212  243  273  304  334  365  396  424  455  485  516  546  577  608  638  669  699  730  761  789  820  850  881  911  942
[33]  973 1003 1034 1064 1095 1126 1155 1186 1216 1247 1277 1308 1339 1369 1400 1430 1461
```

First Day of Month WeekDays

```
> unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month"))
 [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01" "2013-04-01" "2013-05-01" "2013-06-01" "2013-07-01" "2013-08-01" "2013-09-01" "2013-10-01" "2013-11-01" "2013-12-01"
[13] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2014-04-01" "2014-05-01" "2014-06-01" "2014-07-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-09-01" "2014-10-01" "2014-11-01" "2014-12-01"
[25] "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" "2015-03-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-05-01" "2015-06-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-08-01" "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-11-01" "2015-12-01"
[37] "2016-01-01" "2016-02-01" "2016-03-01" "2016-04-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-06-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-08-01" "2016-09-01" "2016-10-01" "2016-11-01" "2016-12-01"
[49] "2017-01-01"
> wday(unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month")))
 [1] 3 6 6 2 4 7 2 5 1 3 6 1 4 7 7 3 5 1 3 6 2 4 7 2 5 1 1 4 6 2 4 7 3 5 1 3 6 2 3 6 1 4 6 2 5 7 3 5 1
> weekdays(unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month")))
 [1] "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Friday"    "Monday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Sunday"    "Wednesday"
[14] "Saturday"  "Saturday"  "Tuesday"   "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Monday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Sunday"   
[27] "Sunday"    "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Monday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Tuesday"   "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"  
[40] "Friday"    "Sunday"    "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Saturday"  "Tuesday"   "Thursday"  "Sunday"
```

Last Day of Month WeekDays

```
> unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month"))-1
 [1] "2012-12-31" "2013-01-31" "2013-02-28" "2013-03-31" "2013-04-30" "2013-05-31" "2013-06-30" "2013-07-31" "2013-08-31" "2013-09-30" "2013-10-31" "2013-11-30"
[13] "2013-12-31" "2014-01-31" "2014-02-28" "2014-03-31" "2014-04-30" "2014-05-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-07-31" "2014-08-31" "2014-09-30" "2014-10-31" "2014-11-30"
[25] "2014-12-31" "2015-01-31" "2015-02-28" "2015-03-31" "2015-04-30" "2015-05-31" "2015-06-30" "2015-07-31" "2015-08-31" "2015-09-30" "2015-10-31" "2015-11-30"
[37] "2015-12-31" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-29" "2016-03-31" "2016-04-30" "2016-05-31" "2016-06-30" "2016-07-31" "2016-08-31" "2016-09-30" "2016-10-31" "2016-11-30"
[49] "2016-12-31"
> wday(unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month"))-1)
 [1] 2 5 5 1 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 7 3 6 6 2 4 7 2 5 1 3 6 1 4 7 7 3 5 1 3 6 2 4 7 2 5 1 2 5 7 3 5 1 4 6 2 4 7
> weekdays(unique(floor_date(dateSeq, "month"))-1)
 [1] "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Sunday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Saturday"  "Tuesday"  
[14] "Friday"    "Friday"    "Monday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Sunday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday" 
[27] "Saturday"  "Tuesday"   "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Friday"    "Monday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"   
[40] "Thursday"  "Saturday"  "Tuesday"   "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Monday"    "Wednesday" "Saturday"
```